# Appending data to a CSV in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm writing a script that iterates over folders and then scans each folders file content and appends the data to a central CSV. I'm just wondering if its better for each file to open and append the data or to open the CSV file and run the loop inside, eg.

```
for dir_name in os.listdir('Some/Folder/Name'):
    df = folderstats.folderstats(f'Some/Folder/Name/{dir_name}', ignore_hidden=True)
    with open('exported_data.csv', 'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

or (i don't know if this works, or if the theory is right but code is wrong)

```
with open('exported_data.csv', 'a') as f:
    for dir_name in os.listdir('Some/Folder/Name'):
        df = folderstats.folderstats(f'Some/Folder/Name/{dir_name}', ignore_hidden=True)
        df.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

Which is correct? I have about 100,000+ files to get data from and append.

Comment: The first proposed solution will open and then close your 'exported_data.csv' file every time it goes round the for loop which makes it wasteful and slower. The second proposed solution doesn't have this problem.